# Wordpress insert unwanted cell padding

Tags: css, wordpress

In wordpress I have padding without any sense!

I format a table with custom css: padding:0 margin:0, in tags td, tr, tbody.
Inside a cell I insert an input[text] with padding:0 margin:0 width:100% height:100%. I still have some space between cell borders and input box.

Testing the TD with Chrome or Safari inspector, I see a computed padding space in graphic view but style inspector tell me that padding is zero.

What’s happening??

This is the page code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Room
            </td>
            <td>
                Uscita
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="insertCellStyle">
                <select class="insertCellStyle" id="Location">
                    <option value="1">
                        Room A
                    </option>
                    <option value="2">
                        Room B
                    </option>
                    <option value="3">
                        Mensa
                    </option>
                    <option value="4">
                        Menza
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="insertCellStyle">
                <input type="text" class="insertCellStyle" style="height:100%; width:100%;" id="Exit">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="inserisci" id="Insert" class="insertCellStyle">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And these are the CSS:

```
.insertCellStyle {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
}

td.insertCellStyle {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
}

input[type="text"].insertCellStyle {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: check if all elements in td have equal height? i think one of the element will have extra height which i effecting all other td height

Comment: if there is a image or button in td decrease the height and see if it works

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or a link to the website reproducing the problem?

Comment: full code in context or it didn't happen

Comment: Thanks. Code added. It’s enough add the styles to custom CSS and create a new page with this code.